# How to make js function delete one element from array and add another instead?

Tags: javascript

so I want to make JS function, that adds random string from my array to HTML, then remove it and add another instead of it. My code now does everything I want to, it just doesn't remove past element and adds another one instead.

In other words - I just want a simple text slide.

MY HTML:

```
 <section style="height: 100vh;" class="">
      <div class="container pt-2 pb-2">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center text-uppercase">
            <div>
              <h1>
                Mes teikiame
              </h1>
                <div class="scroller">
                  <span>
                  </span>
                </div>
              <h1>
                Paslaugas
              </h1>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

MY JS:

```
// Selecting elements
let scrollerSpan = document.querySelector('.scroller > span')
// Creating elements
let textInsideScroller = document.createElement('span')
// Class add
textInsideScroller.classList.add('text-inside-scroller')

// Function generating service name in random order for scroller
const dynamicServiceNames = () => {
    const serviceNames = ['example1', 'example2', 'example3', 'example4', 'example5', 'example6', 'example7'];
    const randomName = serviceNames[rand(0, serviceNames.length)];
    textInsideScroller.append(randomName)
    scrollerSpan.append(textInsideScroller)    
};


// Executing my function

let i = 1;
setInterval(function()
{
    dynamicServiceNames(i++);
}, 1000)
```

**UPDATE:
Tried to solve this issue by adding this to the function:**

```
// Function generating service name in random order for scroller
const dynamicServiceNames = () => {
    const serviceNames = ['grožio', 'voljerų gaminimo', 'apskaitos priežiūros', 'kasinėjimo', 'metinių ataskaitų teikimo', 'deklaracijų ruošimo', 'barščių virimo'];
    const randomName = serviceNames[rand(0, serviceNames.length)];
    textInsideScroller.append(randomName)

    if (scrollerSpan.contains(textInsideScroller)){
        scrollerSpan.remove(textInsideScroller)
    }
    else{
    scrollerSpan.append(textInsideScroller)
    }
    
};
```

But this didn't helped. Now the random string comes from array, but only one time -- I need to refresh the page in order to get another random string....

Comment: And what have you tried to solve the delete part? What was your problem solving that?

Comment: Updated my post with edit

Comment: Before remove, get the index. Then, insert with that index. It's this easy to replace an element of an array.

Comment: Why don't you replace the string instead of removing one and adding another.?

Comment: sorry for probably dumb question, but how can I replace the string instead of removing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just update the innerHTML property of scrollerSpan with randomName.Also,I updated the rand function with Math.random to test this out.

```
// Selecting elements
let scrollerSpan = document.querySelector('.scroller > span')
// Function generating service name in random order for scroller
const dynamicServiceNames = () => {
console.log('inside function')
    const serviceNames = ['example1', 'example2', 'example3', 'example4', 'example5', 'example6', 'example7'];
    
     const randomName = serviceNames[Math.floor(Math.random()*serviceNames.length)];
    scrollerSpan.innerHTML= `<span>${randomName}</span`;   
};


// Executing my function

let i = 1;
setInterval(function()
{
        console.log('in function')
    dynamicServiceNames(i++);
}, 1000)
```

Comment: Damn, thank you so much. :) This did the work. I'm still a newbie here working on my first projects and I completed forgot about innerHTML. Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score -1):

`splice` might be what you're looking for:

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3];

array.splice(1, 1, 5);
// from index 1, remove 1 element, insert 5

console.log(array); // [1, 5, 3];
```